# UIView.animate -->Cannot convert value

Tags: uiview

my code dont give me a error as "Cannot convert value of type '() -> Void' to expected argument type '((Bool) -> Void)?''could you please help to finger it out?

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 2.0, y: 2.0)
        }, completion: {() -> Void in
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

the completion block expects a boolean to that what the error is, use this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 2.0, y: 2.0)
        }) { (_) in
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
```